# Как вывести пользователя с максимальным возрастом?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Здравствуйте!
необходимо вывести имя, фамилию и максимальный возраст, т.к. столбца `age` у меня нет, я высчитую `max(age)` таким образом  :

```
select max(age) from (select DATEDIFF (YY, BirthDate, GETDATE()) -
CASE
WHEN DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YY, birthdate, GETDATE()), birthdate)
> GETDATE() THEN 1
ELSE 0
END AS [age] 
from Employees) x
```

каким образом я помимо максимального возраста могу вывести и имя/фамилию обладателя этого возраста?
п.с Когда в первом запросе я указываю помимо `max(age)` еще и `firstname`, `lastname` ничего не получается

Comment: select lastname, firstname,  DATEDIFF (YY, BirthDate, GETDATE()) -
CASE
 WHEN DATEADD(YY, DATEDIFF(YY, birthdate, GETDATE()), birthdate)
 > GETDATE() THEN 1
 ELSE 0
END AS [age] 
from Employees 


таким образом получается вывод всех имен и фамилий с возрастами, но не с максимальным(

Comment: В смысле, надо вывести самого старого человека? А какой формат BirthDate?

Comment: @DanielProtopopov именно так, datetime

Comment: А зачем тогда делать конвертацию в количество лет? Насколько я знаю в MSSQL можно делать order by date asc

Comment: @DanielProtopopov я совсем новичек  и многого не знаю , как я понимаю order by date asc выдаст мне так же все даты.
Мне же нужно имя фамилия и возраст только самого старого

Comment: Чтобы выбрать самого старого просто берете самого первого, отсортированного по увеличивающейся дате рождения - смотрите ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT TOP 1 
    firstname, 
    lastname, 
    DATEDIFF(BirthDate, YY, GETDATE()) AS age 
ORDER BY BirthDate ASC
```

Comment: Спасибо! гениально просто!)