# Как выбрать максимальное значение в столбце?

Tags: sql, sql-server

У меня есть таблица которая состоит из 2 столбцов

```
 OrderID   OrderDate
-------------------------------
 1021      1976-07-04 00:00:00
 2312      1976-07-05 00:00:00
 9372      1976-07-06 00:00:00
 1241      1976-07-06 00:00:00
```

мне нужно вывести день в который было совершено наибольшее количество заказов
как посчитать количество заказов я понял

```
select OrderDate,COUNT(OrderID)
from Orders
group by OrderDate)
```

выводит вот такой результат

```
OrderDate             (без имени)
---------------------------------
1976-07-04 00:00:00    1
1976-07-05 00:00:00    1
1976-07-06 00:00:00    2
```

как мне вывести только день с максимальным количеством заказов?

Comment: `order by 2 desc limit 1` (если в вашем диалекте sql есть limit)

Comment: Cкорее всего все сводится к банальному ```MAX```, в SQLite, например, ```select max(orderdate) from orders;```

Comment: MS SQL server Manegement Studio  приходится использовать так как на парах используют именно его
помимо всего мне нужно найти не максимальную дату, а дату с максимальным количеством заказов

Comment: значит вбиваем в гугле "MS SQL limit" и видим, что в его диалекте используется `select top 1 ... order by 2 desc` А в дальнейшем _всегда_ указывайте в тегах вопроса с какой СУБД вы работаете

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вывести пользователя с максимальным возрастом?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/623378/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc)

Comment: Один день, или все с максимумом?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 OrderDate,COUNT(OrderID) AS CountZ
from Orders 
group by OrderDate ORDER BY CountZ DESC;
```